# When I press a ListView item keep highlight [Android]

Tags: android, list, listview, view

When I select a element of my ListView during 2 o 3 seconds and then, move my finger to other element and stop pressed, the first element selected keeps highlight all the time. How can I fix this???

Thank you!!!

I forgot to say, the languaje used is Kotlin:

```
    lvLevels.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, v, i, l ->
        Log.i(TAG, "${mapLevels[levelsNameList[i]]}")
        GlobalStatus.level = mapLevels[levelsNameList[i]]
        Log.i(TAG, "Prueba level -> ${GlobalStatus.level}")
        GlobalStatus.levelNumber = i + 1

        val intent = Intent(this@LevelsActivity, TheoryActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

The apdapter:

```
class LevelAdapter(context: Context?, levels: List<String>) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.listitem_levels, levels) {

val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
val levelsList: List<String> = levels
private val LEVEL = " LEVEL "

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    var item: View? = convertView // !!

    if (convertView == null) {
        item = inflater.inflate(
                if (position < GlobalStatus.user!!.userLevel!!) {
                    R.layout.listitem_levels
                } else {
                    R.layout.listitem_level_disable
                },
                null
        )
    }

    item!!.lblLevelNumber.text = "$LEVEL ${(position + 1)}"
    item.lblLevelDescription.text = levelsList[position]

    return item
}

override fun isEnabled(position: Int) = (position < GlobalStatus.user!!.userLevel!!)
```

}

Comment: Set `cacheColorHint` to `transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using either onClickListener or onTouchListener to handle your touch events. Please provide code from now on. I will edit this if you provide some code.

If you're using onTouchListener, which you probably should be, you want to make sure to return "true" if your action is MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, and if it is MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, you want to return false. This boolean value basically says "Do I care about future touch events?". Within those two conditions, you want to set your background accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //implement what ever you want
            return true;
        }
    });
```